# Is it possible to express chainl1 using applicative?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Is it possible to express the `chainl1` combinator from Parsec not using the Monad instance defined by parsec?

```
chainl1 p op =
  do x <- p
     rest x
  where
    rest x = do f <- op
                y <- p
                rest (f x y)
          <|> return x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
chainl1 p op = foldl (flip ($)) <$> p <*> many (flip <$> op <*> p)
```

The idea is that you have to parse `p (op p)*` and evaluate it as `(...(((p) op p) op p)...)`.

It might help to expand the definition a bit:

```
chainl1 p op = foldl (\x f -> f x) <$> p <*> many ((\f y -> flip f y) <$> op <*> p)
```

As the pairs of `op` and `p` are parsed, the results are applied immediately, but because `p` is the right operand of `op`, it needs a `flip`.

So, the result type of `many (flip <$> op <*> p)` is `f [a -> a]`. This list of functions is then applied from left to right on an initial value of `p` by `foldl`.

Comment: Would you care to explain a little bit more? Why the foldl and flip?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but equivalent `Applicative` definition:

```
chainl1 p op =
    p <**>
    rest
  where
    rest = flip <$> op <*>
           p <**>
           pure (.) <*> rest
        <|> pure id
```

Instead of passing of left-side argument `x` explicitly to the right-hand side `op`, this Applicative form 'chains' `op`'s partially applied to their right-side argument (hence `flip <$> op <*> p`) via lifted combinator `(.)` and then applies the leftmost `p` via `(<**>)` to the resulting `rest :: Alternative f => f (a -> a)`.

Comment: When I try this with `chainl1 (read <$> many digit) ((+) <$ char '+' <|> (*) <$ char '*')` on `"1+2*3+4"` I get 17 instead of 13.